# Why load Video extention (.3gp) freeze from photoLibrary swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, video, uiimagepickercontroller, photolibrary

I am trying to select video from PhotoLibrary with extension (.3gp) when I choosing one video.3gp to make app freeze. how to allowed or block that extension files?. I tried so hard but still doesn't work, in debug area and code no error.

Update:

I try to check a video info, if I choose file video example (1).3gp use audio (channel: 1) and(codec: H.263, AMR Narrowband) that app will freeze, and if I convert to change audio file example.3gp load image use `UIImagePickerController` and `photoLibrary` run app is normal. info file look image below

How to block or filter this format file ?

[image: Freeze app load video format 3gp]

Comment: You didn't provide any details, code, errors, or stack traces. How do you expect anyone to be able to help you?

Comment: in debug area and code no error it's clean, I don't know how  trace to find an error